# Create laravel dynamic form array and input records in database

Tags: jquery, arrays, laravel, forms, eloquent

`\`I want to create a form that gets the form array and inputs into the laravel database. I have searched diffrent posts on google and youtube. I have found a working solution but needs the best and efficient approach from you guys.

This is the form i am using to insert multiple rows of records. I am using jquery to create multiple rows that are input into database using logic in the laravel controller.

Form That inputs records:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="myfrm">
    @csrf
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-primary" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                    <th scope="col">Role</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="pull-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="btnAdd()">+</button></th>
                </tr>
            

                <tr id="trow" class="">
                    <td><input type="text" name="title[]" id=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="role[]" id=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email[]" id=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="phone[]" id=""></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="btnDel(this)">x</button></td>
                    
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

The Logic inside the Laravel Controller:
public function bulkcreate(Request $request, Worker $worker){

```
  public function bulkcreate(Worker $worker,Request $request){ 
    
    $title = $request->title;
    $role = $request->role;
    $email = $request->email;
    $phone = $request->phone;

       for($i=0;$i<count($title);$i++){
       
         $datasave = [
            'title'=>$title[$i],
            'role'=>$role[$i],
            'email'=>$email[$i],
            'phone'=>$phone[$i],
            "created_at" =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
            "updated_at" =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now()

            // "created_at" =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

        ];
        
        DB::table('workers')->insert($datasave);
    }
    
     return redirect('/workers')->with('message','Data input success');
    

}
```

To the best of your knowlege. This code has done the job. But i am interested in knowing the more efficient ways doing this job.
I am looking forward to see you guys. Let me know the best techniques. Hopeful to get assistance. Thank you.`
```

Comment: Bro, you can pass the value, not like array of titles, array of emails, and etc. try to pass each row data. so you can save very better way in controller, just like `DB:table('workers')->insert($row);` or maybe it is good to do it like this `Worker::create($row)`. I should to say it is not standard to pass timestamps data. never pass created_at and updated_at.

Comment: and also, you can create validation request file and inject that file instead of Request. inside your validation request file, you can set some validations to check if data is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code is already efficient for array data insertion, you just simply optimize or reduce some code in laravel structure

```
public function bulkcreate(Worker $worker, Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->only(['title', 'role', 'email', 'phone']);

    $workerData = [];

    foreach ($data['title'] as $index => $title) {
        $workerData[] = [
            'title' => $title,
            'role' => $data['role'][$index],
            'email' => $data['email'][$index],
            'phone' => $data['phone'][$index],
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ];
    }

    Worker::insert($workerData);

    return redirect('/workers')->with('message', __('Data has been inserted successfully.'));
}
```